# Using Azure B2C and Sign in with Apple / MSAL.JS / Implicit Flow - Acquiring token silent failing with X-Frame Deny error

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-ad-b2c, msal.js, sign-in-with-apple, implicit-flow

I am currently using a React app which uses MSAL.js to authenticate with an Apple Identity Provider I have registered in Azure B2C. I have based my implementation on a guide: [Post-GA Revisit of “Sign In with Apple” for Azure AD B2C](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-developer-community-blog/post-ga-revisit-of-quot-sign-in-with-apple-quot-for-azure-ad-b2c/ba-p/1083814)

Everything is working with the exception of the access token request, which I try to acquire silently after sign in. I am currently getting an X-Frame Deny error that is occurring in the iFrame msal.js uses and it falls back to a acquireTokenRedirect which asks the user to login again (not a great user experience) and then it works.

Error from the browser console:

Refused to display 'https://appleid.apple.com/auth/authorize?client_id=com.my.clientid&redirect_uri=https://myb2ctenant.b2clogin.com%2foauth2%2fauthresp&response_type=code&scope=email&response_mode=form_post&nonce=nonce&state=StateProperties%3drandomCharshere' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.

Unfortunately, Apple's documentation around the implicit flow with their endpoint is limited.

My two questions are:

1. I'm wondering if the hidden iFrame technique to acquire the token silently just may not be possible with Sign in with Apple. Has anyone had success implementing this?
2. I know when facing this exact X-Frame deny issue with other identity providers such as Google you can pass a login_hint into the acquireTokenSilent request which allows interaction to be skipped (for example if the user has multiple accounts and gets to the account selection screen in the iFrame). I haven't had any success passing in various claims as a login_hint to the Apple Provider though (and documentation on it seems to be non-existent).

Comment: Take a network trace to see if the cookies are being lost.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Where should I be looking? It looks like all the cookies on the Apple calls are there for each call but I could look closer. I did notice that on the initial b2c authresp (right before the access token call fails), there is a 'x-ms-cpim-sso' cookie present, however on the subsequent 302 call (acquireTokenRedirect) that cookie is no longer there.. but that call to Apple works.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in msal.js occurs due to browser extension cookie blockers / third party cookies disabled in browsers.

To fix this, MSAL.js v2 mitigates this in most scenarios by using the auth code flow instead of the implicit flow. Please refer [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-browser#implicit-flow-vs-authorization-code-flow-with-pkce) document

Comment: I see ok. This might be something I have to wait for. Any idea on when the MSAL.js v2 release will be? And will it be compatible with B2C on that release?

Comment: Hi @PhilipYoung, You can now use v2 endpoint with MSAL.js currently.

Comment: Hi @Hari Krishna, sorry, I don't understand. Doesn't B2C use the v2 endpoint already? Is there any configuration I need to be setting with MSAL.js to ensure it is?

Comment: Hi @PhilipYoung, you need to configure a client_secret additionally to use auth code flow. Hope [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-javascript-auth-code) tutorial will help.

Comment: Ah I see ok. In order to use this I must use MSAL 2.0 with PKCE flow, correct? Do you know when it will be released ? (Production ready?)

Comment: Hi @PhilipYoung,MSAL.js 2.0 is now generally available with support for authorization code flow pkce

Comment: Thanks for the update Hari, that is exciting news! Unfortunately I see on their release page it's not B2C ready yet, any idea when that will be? "Important: MSAL.js 2.0 with Authorization Code Flow is not yet available for B2C tenants (coming soon)." https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-browser

Comment: Hi @PhilipYoung,I will ask my team and update you soon.

Answer (score 0):

**RENEWAL REQUEST**

You should send **prompt=none** on the renewal request, to prevent the login page from trying to render on an iframe, as in my [Token Renewal](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/24/user-sessions-and-token-renewal/) blog post.

**APPLE COOKIE RESTRICTIONS**

You may also be running into Safari cross site cookie restrictions, as described at the top of my [Token Renewal Problems](https://authguidance.com/2019/09/09/spa-token-renewal-challenges/) post. If so, see if changing the browser default setting influences behaviour.

**POSSIBLE SOLUTIONS**

Using refresh tokens in some form (either in the browser or wrapped in cookies) may be the way to go, rather than iframe based renewal.

Comment: Thanks for the response - this sounds promising but I believe either B2C or msal.js is already sending prompt=none for me based on this type of flow, I'm not sure I am able to configure it or need to. I am testing it on Chrome and have definitely run into the Safari issue you mention.